# Generating large drawing lists in R

Tags: r

Say I have a list in R like so,

```
[1] 3 5 4 7
```

And I want to generate all "drawings" from this list, from 1 up to the value of each number.  For example,

1 1 1 1

1 1 1 2

1 1 1 3

...

2 3 3 1

2 3 3 2

2 3 3 3

...

3 5 4 7

I know I have used rep() in the past to do something very similar, which works for lists of 2 or 3 numbers (i.e. something like 1 4 5), but I'm not sure how to generalize this here.

Thoughts?

Comment: `expand.grid(Map(seq,c(3,5,4,7)))`?

Comment: Excellent, this worked.  Is there any way to turn each row into a list?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work using lapply(c(1:length(foo[,1])), function(x) unlist(foo[x,], use.names=FALSE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, use `Map` function to apply `seq` to elements of your vector, then use `expand.grid` to generate `data.frame` with Cartesian product of result's elements:

```
head(expand.grid(Map(seq,c(3,5,4,7))))

  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1    1    1    1    1
2    2    1    1    1
3    3    1    1    1
4    1    2    1    1
5    2    2    1    1
6    3    2    1    1
```